# Powershell delete 6 days old folder

Tags: c#, powershell, automation, teamcity

I have to make PS script to integrate it with our Automation Software. I am beginner in PS, and I made some tries, but still without success. This is my task.
I have one Parameter that will be used as Input Parameter. That will be remote Disk Path
%setupRootPath%. This Directory has multiple sub directories like (Beta, Testing, Release, Etc.) Each of it has Project name. In continous integration system each projekt get Build Nomber, so at the end I got something like

- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektA\Build1000
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektA\Build1003
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektA\Build1004
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektB\Build1007
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektB\Build1008
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektB\Build1009
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektB\Build10010
- %setupRootPath%\SystemTesting\ProjektA\Build1002

At the moment there are hundreds of Projects, and I made C# Code that make what I want, but it will be great if I can run it with a sheduler via PS instead of C#

So here is C# Code

```
class Program
{
    const string rootDirPath = @"\\pcName\AutomationProcess\Deployment";
    const int keepNum = 1;
    const int deployDepth = 2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var delDir = new DirectoryInfo(rootDirPath);
        var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        int currentDetph = 0;
        var deployPathes = new Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, int>();
        GetDeployDirectories(delDir, currentDetph, deployPathes);

        foreach (var projektDir in deployPathes.Keys)
        {
            var dirInfoArray = projektDir.GetDirectories();
            if (dirInfoArray != null)
            {
                var sortedDeploymentDirs = from d in dirInfoArray
                                           where (currentDateTime - d.LastWriteTime).Days > 6
                                           orderby d.LastWriteTime
                                           select d;
                var deploymentDirsArray = sortedDeploymentDirs.ToArray();
                if (deploymentDirsArray.Length > keepNum)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < deploymentDirsArray.Length - keepNum; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Delete: {0}", deploymentDirsArray[i].FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void GetDeployDirectories(DirectoryInfo currentDirectory, int currentDetph, Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, int> resultDictionary)
    {
        currentDetph++;

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in currentDirectory.GetDirectories())
        {
            if (currentDetph < deployDepth)
            {
                subDir.Refresh();
                GetDeployDirectories(subDir, currentDetph, resultDictionary);
            }
            else if (currentDetph == deployDepth)
            {
                resultDictionary.Add(subDir, currentDetph);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cant remove all old files, I have to remove all files older than 6 days, but leave the last build even if its older.

So after delete I should get for example such a result

- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektA\Build1000 (Deleted)
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektA\Build1003 (Deleted)
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektA\Build1004 (Older if deleted then none, Skipped)
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektB\Build1007 (Deleted)
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektB\Build1008 (Deleted)
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektB\Build1009 (Not older than 6 days, Skipped)
- %setupRootPath%\Beta\ProjektB\Build10010 (Not older than 6 days, Skipped)
- %setupRootPath%\SystemTesting\ProjektA\Build1002 (Older but only one, Skipped)

I will give a try tommorow. But if anyone will help. I will be greatefull :)
Here below is my current state.
It works, but only when I give the whole Projekt file, but not the root only ;(

```
param([String] $delpath=\\pcName\AutomationProcess\Deployment\Beta\ProjektA\",[String] $keepNum="1")
function Get-SubDirDate($directory)
{
    $datetime = $directory.LastWriteTime
    $SubDirDatealldir = gci $directory.FullName -filter * | ? { $_.PSisContainer -eq $true} 
    $SubDirDatealldir = @($SubDirDatealldir)
    foreach ($subdir in $SubDirDatealldir)
    {
        $subdir = $subdir -as [system.io.directoryinfo]

        if ($subdir)
        {
            $days = $subdir.LastWriteTime

            if ($days -ge $datetime)
            {
                $datetime = $days
            }
        }
    }
    $datetime
}

cd $delpath
$localdir = get-location
if ($localdir.Path.IndexOf($delpath) -ne -1)
{
    $datehash = @{}
    $CurrentTime = Get-Date

    # Mach es rekursive ;(

    $alldir = gci -filter * | ? { $_.PSisContainer -eq $true}
    $alldir = @($alldir)

    foreach ($dir in $alldir)
    {
        $dir = $dir -as [system.io.directoryinfo]
        $dir.Refresh()

        if (($dir) -and ($dir.Exists))
        {
            if (!$datehash.ContainsKey($dir.FullName))
            {
                $datehash[$dir.FullName] = Get-SubDirDate $dir
            }
        }
    }

    # Alle Verz. Aelter als 6 Tage bis auf die letzten n(=keepNum) loeschen 
    $itemCount = $datehash.Count

    if ($itemCount -gt ([int]$keepNum))
    {
        # Hash-Array nach Zeitstempel (=Value) absteigend sortieren 
        # (d.h. neuster Eintrag ist erstes Element) und die neusten n Faelle 
        # rausnehmen, damit diese nachfolgend nicht geloescht werden.             
        $datehashSorted = $datehash.GetEnumerator() | 
            Sort-Object Value -Descending | select-object -Last ($itemCount - [int]$keepNum)

        # Alle übrigen, die Älter als 6 Tage sind, löschen   
        $datehashSorted | foreach-object {

            $dir = $_.Name -as [system.io.directoryinfo] 
            $diffdays = ($CurrentTime-$_.Value).Days

            if ($diffdays -ge 6)
            {
               Write-Host ($dir.fullname)
               $dir.Delete($true) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you already have a working program in C#, why not just call it from your powershell script?

Comment: For feature changes. It's easier to change script written in TeamCity Step than mainaining C# Code and App

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after. You could certainly make this more efficient from a code perspective, or easily convert it to a function, but I was trying to make it readable.

```
# Your input parameter
$setupRootPath = "\\pcName\AutomationProcess\Deployment\"

# Retrieve the top level directories (Beta, Testing, Release, etc.).
Get-ChildItem $setupRootPath | Where-Object {$_.PSisContainer -eq $true} | ForEach-Object {
    $topDir = $_

# Pull the list of projects in the current top level dir.
    Get-ChildItem $topDir | Where-Object {$_.PSisContainer -eq $true} | ForEach-Object {
        $projectDir = $_

#Get the list of build folders, sorting by LastWriteTime, skipping the most recent, where the file is older than 6 days; and delete the remaining items.
        Get-ChildItem $projectDir | Where-Object {$_.PSisContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Where-Object {((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).TotalDays -gt 6} | Remove-Item

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
So when I type instad of this | Select-Object -Skip 1
| Select-Object -Skip $keepNum should work aswell. But with this Solution I cant configure Depth of Build Projects. Anyway I will try it today. Thank you very much again :)